# How do I get all the entries for a certain month and year?

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to do

```
var dt = DateTime.Now.ToString();

string query = "SELECT * FROM Gigs where Date >= '"+dt+"';";
```

it appears to work - except it gets entries for future months

I then do

```
var dt = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3).ToString();

string query = "SELECT * FROM Gigs where Date >= '"+dt+"';";
```

And I get the same result which isn't expected

If today is January 1st, I want to get all the entries for January, but none for February.

This is readonly data, no concern of SQL injection

Comment: Are you saying there are rows that have a Date in the next 3 months that are included in both result sets?  Also you should consider using sql parameters.

Comment: Two things:  **1.** You're getting dates *later than* the date specified, not older than, and **2.** while you're safe here, you really should always use parameterized queries, otherwise you will be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks

Comment: "you really should always use parameterized queries" this is news to me, know the reason why by any chance?

Comment: Have you debugged query value? Maybe the Date it's not in the right format expected for sql. Try ToString("yyyyMMdd"). And as other people said this kind of construction is very vulnerable.

Comment: You should use paramtereized queries because it helps the optimizer reuse plans and it protects you from sql injection.

Comment: I'm still giggling at BobbyTables... This is read only, no concern of SQL injection, if there was I'd use params

Comment: If you didn't know about parameterised queries, MDQ, Bobby might just have saved you from getting fired. Turns out you're aware of the issue and clued up enough to know its not an issue in this scenario, but an _awful_ lot of people who post here haven't a clue about SQL injection (never heard of it or don't care). Imho you should be thanking him for the helpful comment not giggling.

Comment: "no concern of SQL injection" here goes a joke "is your son's name really "Robert'); DROP TABLE Students; " :)

Comment: Jon Skeet (and probably Chuck Norris) could inject SQL into that...  See http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/08/the-bobbytables-culture/ for an example of injecting through a DateTime

Comment: Are you asking to get all the items in the future, or just all the items that match the month you specify?  IE, if the date is January 1st 2015, only get items for January 2015?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, why do you need to calculate date in C# and pass it to SQL query?
You can use `DATEADD` and `GETDATE()` to avoid that:

```
--Will get three months before:
select DATEADD(MONTH, 3, GETDATE())
```

Second, you got three months in future. Are you sure that you don't want to  use -3:

```
var dt = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3).ToString();
```

Third: use  parameterized queries, here is the example:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "SELECT *   FROM [Test].[dbo].[SomeDates] WHERE dt > @MyDate";
                    var param = new SqlParameter("@MyDate", SqlDbType.DateTime2) { Value = DateTime.Now };
                    command.Parameters.Add(param);
                    var result = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (result.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(result.GetDateTime(0));
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Update regarding second**: looks like you do want to get query in future.

**Update #2**: Even if you is not concerned about SQL injection (but you **must** be), you should use parameterized queries since framework will take care of date time formats and conversions. Otherwise it may work on your machine but won't work on other machine/production.

Comment: Regarding your second point, they really should be using `[Date ] <= getdate()` to get less than the current date (and be using brackets around `Date`, since it's a reserved word) (unless I misunderstand the meaning of "older")

Comment: Yes, that's what it being said.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to convert the date to a string, make sure your region settings don't return a different date for sql server if it uses different region settings. June 5th can be 05-06-2015 for you, but if you pass that in sql-server with en-us it will interpret it as May 6th.

Conversion from date to string for sql server should always be done using the universal format yyyy-MM-dd, which won't be interpreted wrong in most software, regardless of regional settings.

If you use SqlParameters as suggested you don't really need to worry about these mismatches, so another + for SqlParameter usage.